# HTML element size in bytes Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, html-lists

How to get the size of an HTML element in  bytes using javascript?

I have a list that represents a conversation

```
<ul>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>how are you?</li>
  <li>fine thanks</li>
  <li>nice to meet you</li>
  <li>nice to mmet you too</li>
</ul>
```

And I want to save that conversation to localStorage, but localStorage limit is 5MB in chrome,  so I need to know the size in bytes for the list to do some validations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027142/calculating-usage-of-localstorage-space on Calculating usage of localStorage space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to convert the element to HTML, then you could give the `<ul>` an ID then use

```
var el = document.getElementById("convo");
var html = el.innerHTML;
window.alert(html.length);
```

Or, if there will be a lot of markup and you want to just get the text, you could loop through the `li` elements and extract just the text and put that in an array.  `JSON.stringify` the result and get its length.

Edit:

Javascript uses `UCS-2` or `UTF-16` internally, both of which are 16 bit encodings.  Assuming Latin text, `<string>.length *2` should be a fairly accurate estimate.

Comment: Length alone might not be enough to accurately get the number of bytes since it depends on the encoding aswell.

Comment: @Mahn -- Given that Javascript uses `UCS-2` or `UTF-16` internally, I'd work off the [unfounded, but good guess] that `.localStorage` uses the same encoding.  While it may be a few bytes off, `<string>.length *2` is a good estimate.

Comment: True, you didn't consider the 16 bits per char on your original answer though, hence the comment :)

Comment: For the record, here's more on the js specifications of string encoding (which is indeed UTF-16): http://stackoverflow.com/a/2219545/1329367 and here it talks about how localStorage uses UTF-16 strings aswell: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7411549/1329367 feel free to add these links to the answer for completeness sake.

Comment: @Mahn -- Its a little more complex than that.  It uses a 16BIT word, but it doesn't have to be `UTF-16`:  Read here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715980/javascript-strings-utf-16-vs-ucs-2