# Web SQL Storage in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, html, ios4, web-sql

Can I use a Web SQL Storage in iPhone

Currently my following code is resulting in error

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Web Storage</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var sessionDB = {}
    sessionDB.webdb = {};
    sessionDB.webdb.db = null;

    function init() {
     console.log("Loading");
     sessionDB.webdb.open();
     sessionDB.webdb.createTable();
     sessionDB.webdb.addRecord("_session_id=9943d50d1b8fdc3794137f5446e94a6e");
     sessionDB.webdb.getSession();
    }

    sessionDB.webdb.open = function() {
      var dbSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      sessionDB.webdb.db = openDatabase("sessionDB", "1.0", "Session Database", dbSize);
    }

    sessionDB.webdb.createTable = function() {
      var db = sessionDB.webdb.db;
      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        // make id auto Increment
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sessions(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, session_id TEXT, added_on DATETIME)", [],successCallbacks,errorCallbacks);
       });
    }

    sessionDB.webdb.addRecord = function(session_id) {
        var db = sessionDB.webdb.db;
        db.transaction(function(tx){
          var addedOn = new Date();
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO sessions(session_id, added_on) VALUES (?,?)",
              [session_id,addedOn],successCallbacks,errorCallbacks);

         });
      }  

    successCallbacks = function(transaction,sqlResult) {
       console.log("SUCCESS :)");
    } 

    errorCallbacks = function(transaction,error) {
       console.log(error.message + " -- " + error.code);
       console.log("ERROR !!!");
     }

    sessionDB.webdb.getSession = function() {
      var db = sessionDB.webdb.db;
      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT session_id FROM sessions limit 1 ;", [], resultSets);
      });
   }   

   resultSets = function (transaction,sqlResult) {
     $("#resultSet").text(sqlResult.rows.item(0).session_id)
   }

  </script>   
</head>
 <body onload="init();">
   <h1> WEB STORAGE EXAMPE </h1>
   <div id="resultSet"> </div>

 </body>
```

Error message stating "**not authorized**" with error **code 5**

The idea is to store the **session_id** in the session tables and I cant approach **localStorage** because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077101/iphone-localstorage-quota-exceeded-err-issue)

The application is not a native application its a traditional client-server application with server returning the above HTML fragment to iPhone browser(safari browser)

Note : **Above code work fine in Desktop browser having Web SQL capabilities**

Thanks
Viren

Comment: Take a look at this: http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/. I've never made used HTML5 on iOS, but this tutorial looks like it would help.

Comment: I have the same issue however I managed to make it randomly work.... Don't know why but it seems to work sometime only when you make a shortcut on the springboard and run it from there as a web app. Try this and tell me if it changes anything

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Safari on iOS has some issue handling the DB. It works if you create a shortcut on your springboard to run as a WebApp.

Comment: Apparently still the same issue on at least iOS 7.0.4. Sad :-(